# variables + loops using web audio api and jquery

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

here's a link to something I've been working on

http://79.170.40.170/johnhartmanportfolio.com/

and a couple of notes
I built a simple 3 band graphic eq and am currently hooking up the filters.
if you click the green button a sine wave will play; the red button will stop it.

if you move any fader (any direction)the low pass filter will tick down (if you open console i am outputting the current filter value to the log)

the problem: I am using if loops to compare the values the problem is once I reach 0 it's kind of like my other loop never gets looked at. I don't know what I am doing wrong perhaps an if loop is not appropriate? that being said its made me revisit assignment and operators but I'm still stuck any help would be much appreciated.

(just the js)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var context = new AudioContext();
  var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
  var volume = context.createGain();
  var biquadFilter = context.createBiquadFilter();
  biquadFilter.type = "lowshelf";
  var eqValue = 1000;
  biquadFilter.frequency.value = eqValue;
  biquadFilter.gain.value = 1;
  volume.gain.value = 0;
  oscillator.start(0)


  $("#playButton").click(function() {
    oscillator.connect(volume);
    volume.connect(biquadFilter)
    biquadFilter.connect(context.destination);
    volume.gain.value = 1;
  });

  $("#stopButton").click(function() {
    volume.gain.value = 0;
  });

  $(".faderStyle").on("slide", function() {

    if (eqValue = 0) {
      biquadFilter.frequency.value += 10;
      console.log(biquadFilter.frequency.value)
    }
    if (eqValue = 1000) {
      biquadFilter.frequency.value -= 10;
      console.log(biquadFilter.frequency.value)
      return (eqValue);
    }
    return (eqValue)
  });

  $(".faderStyle").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    value: 60
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if's` should use either `==` or `===` for comparison.

The equals operator will always set your variable's value, which is not what you want.

`eqValue = 0` will always evaluate as false and should be `eqValue === 0`

`eqValue = 1000` will always evaluate as true and should be `eqValue === 1000`

Comment: ah just as I thought I was messing something up there thank you so much for clarifying

Comment: @VanHartman I often find someone looking over my code will often see something I've missed like this. So easy to do.